Connecting VSCode Desktop (Locally) to Azure Studio Compute Instance through Azure Machine Learning Extension - New
I have been combing the internet for this for a long long time, so your help is very very much appreciated,
I am trying to connect to an Azure Studio Compute Instance through VSCode Desktop and its associated Azure Machine Learning VSCode extension.

Context: While developing in Azure Studio ML Compute instance, I would need to develop in VSCode Desktop locally (VSCode Web in the Azure Studio I have is freezing and the Desktop version link in Azure Studio does not open my VSCode with administrative privileges - and for the work I do I need to develop locally with elevated privileges).

I have tried to connect from VSCode Desktop (local VSCode) to an Azure ML Compute Instance through the Azure Machine Learning Extension (and the associated Remote) last week. It did work through VS Code Azure extension and then suddenly broke a few days later. The error message varies depending on the vs code extension that is being used.
Usually however, the error is either that
the Azure Extension is not installed on the remote or
that the remote listening is not on
that it failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sessionId')
cannot read propoerties of undefined (reading 'sessionId') Source Azure Machine Learning - Remote




The question: So I have managed to make it work before by tweaking the different version number of Azure Machine Learning and Azure Machine Learning Remote at 0.28.0 and 0.32.0 respectively (the most up to date version gave errors and I tweaked on the different versions). The VSCode version I have now is 1.90.2. Please note I have tried to create a new workspace in Azure Studio and new computes and also reinstalled VSCode to the current 1.90.2 version.

Is this a matter of version compatability and what would be the best combinations of version to make it work? What would a quick fix be for this? Should I consider the ssh route for this instead of the extension (note our compute instance is not allowed for now to have a public IP due to the vnet restrictions that are applied on the workspace).


Is this a matter of version compatability and what would be the best combinations of version to make it work?


The Version 0.28.0 and 0.32.0 worked well before, but due to the frequent updates in VSCode and Azure extensions is causing inconsistencies. So, installed below extension and it worked well.


I have checked the release notes for each version that could find a stable combination for the issues.

Open ml.azure.com, and sign-in with the own subscription and Navigate to your application, open terminal.


Click on Edit in VS Code(desktop) and follow the sign process.

When you click on vs code desktop the azure ML remote URL redirects to vs code editor to open.


Signed IN:


In Azure AI - ML studio:

